# Including (not referencing) one Model inside another in the App Engine Datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

People of the stack, hello.

I feel there must be an obvious answer, but I've done a lot of searching and read a lot of documents and code and can't come to it.

(I'm going to obscure some of the actual names and such for confidentiality reasons below...)

This is my first AppEngine project, though I've written a lot of Python.

I am writing a simple application that, conceptually, has only one "database table", one Model - call it Person, it represents a single person in this, er, dog owners club.

Person has a lot of parts, some of them repeating parts with their own internal structure, like "DogsOwned" and "PlayDates".  What I want to have is separate definitions for these parts which I combine together to make a full model, so I have a DogsOwned.py and a PlayDates.py which are referenced in my master file, Person.py.

I reiterate that I don't want a separate DogsOwned or PlayDates "database table"!  I am *only* interested in DogsOwned or PlayDates as included as part of a Person.

Unfortunately, `google.appengine.ext.db.Model` doesn't seem to have a way to *include* another model.  You can use `google.appengine.ext.db.ReferenceProperty` but that seems to *reference* another Object by key, requiring me to "create another database table" (I know my terminology isn't quite right but you get the idea).

So in order to retrieve an entire Person record, it seems to me that there have to have be multiple queries, one to get the Person, and one for each entry in DogsOwned or PlayDates. They'll all share the same entity group so they should be coherent, and it's all supposed to scale - but "I" get billed by Google "by the query" in some sense for this when it comes down to it, so I'd love to keep my query count as low as possible.  Or... perhaps the entity group somehow magically fixes my issue?

Your enlightening comments are solicited!  Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

In other words: I want a Model to contain repeating sub-elements - in pseudocode,

```
struct Person {
  Dog dogsOwned[];
  PlayDates playDates[];
};
```

where Dogs and PlayDates aren't primitive Properties.

Python inheritance is of no use for this - you can't inherit the same class multiple times, and more fundamentally, I want "contains", not "isa".

Comment: I think what you want is the PickleProperty: https://github.com/Arachnid/aetycoon In your model you would store arrays of objects, not additional Models.

Comment: Calvin: I think you've hit the nail on the head.  If you want to write it up as an "answer" I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: And now that I know the answer, you can see a similar answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874009/store-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-gae

Comment: OK, it was StructuredProperty, but in the 2.7 app engine Python source distribution, JsonProperty, PickleProperty AND StructuredProperty are in the same file, so your comment led me to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gosh, I hate to answer my own question, but I dug through the source code and found it!

The answer is `google.appengine.ext.ndb.model.StructuredProperty`.

From the code:

> The StructuredProperty is different from most other properties; it
>   lets you define a sub-structure for your entities.  The substructure
>   itself is defined using a model class, and the attribute value is an
>   instance of that model class.  However it is not stored in the
>   datastore as a separate entity; instead, its attribute values are
>   included in the parent entity using a naming convention (the name of
>   the structured attribute followed by a dot followed by the name of the
>   subattribute).

There's very little documentation aside from the code itself (which is copious) but GvR talks about it [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/appengine-ndb-discuss/1FmgEVK7JNM).

This is exactly what I was looking for.  It's for Python 2.7, which is a little bleeding edge on the App Engine, but I'm starting a new project so I think it'll be fine...

Comment: The NDB docs have some example code and info https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1dsx1hihmMXMJm8wIRu49tJR-KEng80o3wkg4Nlbqn-w#h.1ph4n6-eddoo4

Comment: And NDB has some interesting ways to reduce the number of datastore transactions through caching and batching.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep all entities in the same entity group by having the Person be the parent entity to the other two types (IIRC). If the dogs and play dates can be safely serialized, you can use a StringListProperty for JSON versions of them and keep everything inside the Person entity.

If you want to keep datastore operations low, you can use memcache to prevent repeated reads to popular entities.

Comment: So we're getting to two general classes of solution: either serialize Python "native" classes (through pickle or similar) and put them in slots, or use full "database objects" and rely on caching to prevent hotspots...

Answer (score 0):

i dont really understand your structure but what about other simple classes you subclass with your Person model?

like:

```
class DogsOwned(object):  
    # variables, functions and whatever else you want

class PlayDates(object):  
    # same as above

class Person(db.Model, DogsOwned, PlayDates):
    # the rest of your code.
```

again its pretty unclear what your goal is...

Comment: I'm sorry if it's unclear.  I'm updating the original question to add more information - but this won't do it, not only is multiple inheritance bad but it doesn't handle the main issue, that these fields are repeated.

Comment: @TomSwirly: why do you think its 'bad'?

Comment: Good q!  1. [The Diamond Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem) leads to nasty surprises and the wrong method called.  2. Few objects really _have_ multiple types, usually they _contain_ things of multiple types instead.  Here, you're trying to force a Person to also be a Dog and a PlayDate!  3. Because it allows you exactly one of each base class - in many cases like this one you might want zero, or more than one.  4. Because it couples your interface to more than one other, so two other people can make "correct" changes but have name collisions that break your code.