# Database storing in Google datastore

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, dictionary, google-cloud-datastore

I have to store about 1800 entries of a dictionary in Google Data-Store to be used in the Google App Engine for queries from another server.

The sample dictionary format is :

`{
    u'Plot': u'Sample plot', 
    u'Rated': u'N/A', 
    u'Response': u'True', 
    u'Language': u'English', 
    u'Title': u'Sample Title', 
    u'Country': u'USA'
}`

I have tried searching for an example to do any such entry, but nowhere could I find one for the dictionary entries. Please do help me out of this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store a list of dictionaries in GAE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874009/store-a-list-of-dictionaries-in-gae)

Answer (score 0):

What you describe as a dictionary corresponds to an Entity in [AppEngine Datastore](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/), the sample keys correspond to property names and the sample values correspond to property values.